# I want my body to be scrollable in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and I am trying to scroll my entire scaffold body. I have a StreamBuilder, ListView.builder, and lots of things over there.

Here is my body:

```
body: Column(
          children: [
            StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream:_someStreamingFunction(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Card(
                   child: Container(
                    child:  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: []
                    ),
                   ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                     children: [
                       Text(
                         'Loading',
                          style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                        ),
                       ),
                   SpinKitThreeBounce(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      size: 12.0,
                      ),
                     ],
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount:
                          transactions.length != 0 ? transactions.length : 0,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return CustomTile(.....);
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        });
       ],
     ),
```

I have tried multiple ways to do this, nothing works.

I have cleared some of the code, for better understanding.

Update I have also tried wrapping my body inside SingleChildScrollView

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

This is the error:

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining space in the vertical direction.
These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.

Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum constraints provided by the parent.
```

Comment: Could you please clarify *what* you've tried and *why* it didn't work?

Comment: I have tried scrolling my scaffold body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  **SingleChildScrollView** widget and remove expanded Widget.
like this ur whole page will be scrollable.

Comment: No thats not working

Comment: can u remove expanded widget

Comment: I have updated this issue in the question.

Comment: Thank you soo much after removing the expanded widgets. It is working.

Comment: u can upvote the ans :)

Comment: Do not use a SingleChildScrollView if you're going to have a ListView inside. It breaks the entire logic of the ListView and creates a huge memory issue. You need to use CustomScrollView with Slivers